# multi string replace with one string

Tags: php

multi string replace with one string

I want replace all unwanted string with one

i.e

```
$string='a','b','c','d','e','@','#','%','!';
$replace='';

str_replace($string,$replace,"afsdfasdfasdfasd #%^#^%#@@ ");
```

Comment: Do not post invalid code examples (in the sense, it should work). Also if you thing `str_replace` might do it, take a look into the manual first: http://php.net/str_replace.

Answer (score 1):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) accepts arrays as inputs.

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/str_replace):

> If search and replace are arrays, then `str_replace()` takes a value from each array and uses them to search and replace on subject. If replace has fewer values than search, then an empty string is used for the rest of replacement values. If search is an array and replace is a string, then this replacement string is used for every value of search. The converse would not make sense, though.

So, simply store the search strings in an array, like so:

```
$subject = 'afsdfasdfasdfasd #%^#^%#@@';
$string = array('a','b','c','d','e','@','#','%','!');
echo str_replace($string, '', $subject);
```

**[Demo!](https://eval.in/46145)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace("/[abcde@#%!]/", '', $string)
```